# GREP and TAR all files/directories matching X

Tags: find, grep, tar, gzip

I would like to find and gzip/tarball contents of all the folders matching 
`wordpress` in my directory, but I am having trouble trying to get the command
to work, I thought it was something like

```
find * | tar -zcvf jdaniel/wp-all.tar.gz 'grep wordpress'
```

> tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the search in the find command instead:

```
find ./ -iname '*wordpress*' | tar -zcvf jdaniel/wp-all.tar.gz
```

You could also add `-type d` to the find command, but not sure if that will skip the files in the directories when they are passed to the tar command.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to archive all the directories in the current directory whose names include "wordpress", then just use this:

```
tar -zcvf jdaniel/wp-all.tar.gz *wordpress*
```

That assumes that you're not interested in directories beginning with ".".